keyword argument trying to make google form response generator using python
I'm very new to python. I'm trying to write a script in VS code on macOS using chrome webdriver and selenium that submits responses to a google form - no nefarious reason I promise, just some funny competiton between friends!
I've been somewhat following this tutorial along with some youtube video tutorials
I've got it as far as openning my test form but whenever I run it I get a keyword argument on 'executable_path', and I don't know how to resolve this
the error says:

Exception has occurred: TypeError WebDriver._init_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'   File "/Users/[myname]/Selenium/main.py", line 8, in <module>     browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "users/[myname]/chromedriver", options=option)               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: WebDriver._init_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

here is my code:

from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("-incognito")
option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument("disable-gpu")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/Users/[my name]/chromedriver", options=option)

browser.get("https://forms.gle/R2xt69eWMnXTGrjD6")

# Use the following snippets to get elements by their class names
otherboxes = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span/div/div[1]/label/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div")
submitbutton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/span")

otherboxes[0].click()

submitbutton[0].click()
                                                
#browser.close()    

if anyone can help me or tell me where I'm going wrong please let me know! Thanks!

Seems the tutorial is for an older version of Selenium.
Specifying the executable_path is deprecated. You need to use Service class:
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('path_to_chromedriver')

The same for find_element_by_xpath, it needs to be find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath').
On a related note, using absolute xpath like this is not recommended, it's very brittle and difficult to read. "/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span/div/div[1]/label/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div"
Preferred approach is to find the right element via id, class name, or relative xpath
